# вернуть данные из php в форму

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Есть такой form.php который собирает реквизиты,

```
<?php
$summ = $_POST['summ'];

$m_shop = '453441379';
$m_orderid = '1';
$m_amount = number_format($summ, 2, '.', '');
$m_curr = 'USD';
$m_desc = base64_encode('Test');
$m_key = 'Ваш секретный ключ';

$arHash = array(
    $m_shop,
    $m_orderid,
    $m_amount,
    $m_curr,
    $m_desc
);

$arHash[] = $m_key;

$sign = strtoupper(hash('sha256', implode(':', $arHash)));
?>
```

я `$summ` передаю аяйсом из index.php

```
$("#sub_but").click(function () {
    var summ = parseInt($("#summ").text());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'form.php',
        data: {
            summ: summ
        },
    });
});
```

как вернуть эти данные обратно в форму в index.php после того как php отработает?

```
<form method="post" action="https://payeer.com/merchant/">
            <input type="hidden" name="m_shop" value="<?=$m_shop?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="m_orderid" value="<?=$m_orderid?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="m_amount" value="<?=$m_amount?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="m_curr" value="<?=$m_curr?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="m_desc" value="<?=$m_desc?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="m_sign" value="<?=$sign?>">

            <input type="submit" name="m_process" value="send" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Какие данные конкретно и куда? После сабмита аяксом данные в инпутах формы и так остаются.

Comment: ну я ожидаю, что после клика по ("#sub_but"), значение переменной отправиться в  $summ в php. Но когда я пытаюсь отправить после этого саму форму - платежная система выдает ошибку, что $m_amount не может быть < 0,01. Тоесть либо значение не передается куда надо, либо не вытягивается обратно

Answer (score 1):

form.php:

```
$summ = $_POST['summ'];
$m_shop = '453441379';
$m_orderid = '1';
$m_amount = number_format($summ, 2, '.', '');
$m_curr = 'USD';
$m_desc = base64_encode('Test');
$m_key = 'Ваш секретный ключ';

$arHash = array( // подготовьте массив к возврату в виде объекта json
    'm_shop'    => $m_shop,
    'm_orderid' => $m_orderid,
    'm_amount'  => $m_amount,
    'm_curr'    => $m_curr,
    'm_desc'    => $m_desc
);

$arHash['m_key'] = $m_key;

return json_encode($arHash); // верните данные туда, от куда послан запрос
```

index.html:

```
var $form = $('form#form input'); // форме дали id, что бы однозначно идентифицировать её

$("#sub_but").click(function () {
    var summ = parseInt($("#summ").text());
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'form.php',
        data : {'summ' : summ},
        success: function(data) { // если ajax запрос ОК, data будет содержать $arHash
            $form.each(function(data) {
                // в цикле значения из data подавляются в соответствующие input
                // например, в input[name="m_shop"] подставится значение data['m_shop'] etc.
                $(this).val(data[$(this).attr('name')]);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: почему-то пустые строки возвращает

Comment: а если саму форму засунуть в этот PHP и редирект на этот же файл. только из index нужно передать значение summ и чтобы при редиректе на php уже все данные были. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Pavel Persianov код рабочий - проверен. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно какие именно данные, ну сделать это можно вернув в json на view(js),предварив в PHP простой проверкой на аякс && post, а дальше в js, уже подменять полученные данные в нужные инпуты. Для этого нужно немного модицифировать ajax:

```
     $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'form.php',
                data: {
                    summ: summ
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }

            });
```

в result будет то- что вы вернете с PHP

Comment: в консоле пустая строка возвращается

Comment: Такс. Начнем с начала. Задача стоит отправить форму на PHP?

Comment: Судя по Вашему коду я вообще не вижу ни #sub_but, ни #summ с которого вы "забираете данные"

Comment: на php мне нужно отправить только значение одной переменной - это $summ, чтобы дальше эту форму можно было подтвердить и отправить

Comment: ну  #sub_but и  #summ это обычные кнопка и переменная в которую я записываю значение, они работают корректно